# command make can not recognize " [ " of Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I had learned Makefile before, but there is a problem in Makefile when I typed the command "make" today.

Here is the piece of code:

```
[ -d _build ] || mkdir _build
```

And the error:

```
'[' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

and there is my Make version:

```
GNU Make 3.82.90
Built for i686-pc-mingw32
```

Can anybody tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the actual makefile as the context in which the code shown is used is important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your makefile was written for Linux/Unix and you are running it under Windows.

In a makefile, the commands that compose the recipes of the targets are 
written in the language of the OS shell. Under Windows the shell is `cmd`.
Under Linux by default it is `bash`. Under other Unix variants it is `sh` or
some other shell.

```
[ -d _build ] || mkdir _build
```

is a valid command for `bash` and some other Linux/Unix shells. Not for
`cmd`. The same will be true of almost all the other recipe commands in the
makefile. You have just hit the first such problem.

Your makefile is of no use under native Windows. On Windows you have a chance
of running it in a Linux virtual machine, or under the Windows 10 Subsystem for Linux,
or under a Unix-like environment for Windows such as Cygwin or MSYS2. You may
well need to install tools that the makefile recipes require in that Linux/Unix-like
system.

If the makefile is simple you can consider translating the unrecognized shell
commands into `cmd` commands, if you are able.